# Local code not in GIT, how to sync with remote repo

Tags: git

I used an open source library for a project several years ago and made quite a few additions and changes to the source.  For some dumb reason I didn't fork or clone the repo at the time, I just downloaded the source as a zip so I don't have the code in local repo.

I'd like to use this library again taking advantage of the last several years of commits to the source repo, while also retaining the changes I've made... but I'm not sure how to do that without overwriting one set of changes or the other.

I'd like to end up with a fork of the repo with a branch in it that is up to date with the main branch of the source repo and also has my changes incorporated.  Any advice?

Comment: … You’ll have to figure out how to merge your changes with the current version.

Comment: isn't there a README or version.txt or Changelog file which would help you spot the initiail version ?

Answer (score 2):

```
git clone <url> project
cd project
```

Find a commit that is at least as old as the code you started work with, and create a new branch from that commit. Check that out, replace the code with your modified code, and commit. Then merge the main branch into your branch, dealing with whatever merge conflicts you find.

```
git branch my_changes <OLD_COMMIT_ID>
git checkout my_changes
cp -r your_modified_code/ .
git commit
git merge main
```

If the merge conflicts are overwhelming, you may want to start by merging older commits first, so that you only have a few conflicts at a time to deal with. Eventually, you'll have a branch that is the up-to-date upstream plus your changes.

Answer (score 1):

By any chance, do you remember the last commit before you downloaded the source code? If you do, this will be a possible workaround.

1. Go to the commit, browse files, clone repo
2. Paste your changes from the source code on your system to the newly cloned repo
3. Inspect diff and decide which changes you want to keep, commit them
4. Set the open source repo as remote, and rebase the recent changes, this might require quite a bit of conflict resolution
5. Push the changes to your fork

Good luck!

Comment: "*By any chance, do you remember the last commit before you downloaded the source code?*" Or the date when zip was downloaded.